# mysql create table query taking too long to execute

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join, amazon-rds

I am running a mysql query.
Select query gets executed but create table query gives timeout issue. what can be the issue here.
below is the query:

```
Create table application_details as (
Select
app.*,
temp.occupation,
temp.monthly_income as 'payment'
 from app_ss as app
              inner JOIN v_employ temp
              ON (app.application_id = temp.application_id)
         )
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create a table with shown query then server must:

1. Execute the query and obtain complete output (not references array but complete values array, and it is possible that this output will be materialized).
2. Scan all values in each column and determine proper datatype and another base properties for each column of the table to be created.
3. Create a table.
4. Insert all values into the table.

Of course this process cannot be fast, especially when the output of the SELECT part is huge.

PS. Single quote chars in `temp.monthly_income as 'payment'` are not correct (i.e. correct syntax but wrong ideology - see comments) - use backticks instead.

Comment: Enclosing alias with single quotes is allowed by mysql, however, you cannot use single quoted strings to refer to an alias. So, select 1 as 'alias' works, but select fieldname as 'alias' group by 'alias' will not.

Comment: @Shadow *Enclosing alias with single quotes is allowed by mysql* Can you point me to the Reference Manual citate? I know that MySQL uses backticks and, when ANSI_QUOTES mode is enabled, doublequote chars. MySQL *may* (but don't have to) correctly distinguish that the literal enclosed with single quotes is an alias - sometimes, when it is obvious that the literal can be alias only, in all another cases this produces syntax error.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-with-alias.html

Comment: @Shadow Thank you. But I take it as "you may... but you should not".

Comment: The should not does not mean it is incorrect. The alias part in the question follows correct syntax. You may not like it, but that's not the same as incorrect.

Comment: @Shadow Yes, I agree.